# How to print the contents of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently in the process of testing my ArrayPhoneDirectory file, which involves me testing all of the individual methods set out in that file. 
After testing my addChangeEntry method, I need to print out the contents of my array (newdir) in order to check that the 3 contacts i have added are there, but am not sure of the best way to do this.

ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester code:

```
public class ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //creates a new PhoneDirectory
    PhoneDirectory newdir = new ArrayPhoneDirectory();

    System.out.println("ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester Running");
    System.out.println("********************************* \n");

    System.out.println("TEST 1: addChangeEntry");
    System.out.println("********************** \n");

    newdir.addChangeEntry("Joe Perkins", "07762573872");
    newdir.addChangeEntry("Annie Howell", "0876273862");
    newdir.addChangeEntry("Buzz Killington", "99999999999");


    // PRINT ARRAY TO PROVE THEY HAVE BEEN ADDED
```

any help with this would be much appreciated.

EDIT- ADDING CODE:

ArrayPhoneDirectory code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ArrayPhoneDirectory implements PhoneDirectory {

private static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 100;
private int capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;

//holds telno of directory entries
private int size = 0;

//Array to contain directory entries
private DirectoryEntry[] theDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[capacity];


//Holds name of data file to be read
private String sourceName = null;

/**
 * Flag to indicate whether directory was modified since it was last loaded
 * or saved.
 */
private boolean modified = false;

// PUBLIC INTERFACE METHODS

public void loadData(String sourceName) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceName).useDelimiter("\\Z");

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        String telno = scan.nextLine();

        add(name, telno);
    }
}

/**
 * find method is called, returning the position in the array of the given
 * name.
 */
public String lookUpEntry(String name) {
    find(name);
    return null;

}

/**
 * for loop that checks every DirectoryEntry inside theDirectory and then
 * checks it against the name and telno given in the parameter, if both are
 * equal, the telno is updated, else it is added to theDirectory
 *
 */

public String addChangeEntry(String name, String telno) {
    try {
        for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
            if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
                x.setNumber(telno);
                return x.getNumber();
            }
            add(name, telno);  
        }

    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("NullPointerExcepttion : " + e.getMessage());

    }

    finally {


    }
    return null;
}



//TO COMPLETE
public String removeEntry(String name) {
    return null;
}

/**
 * A new PrintWriter object is created, and a for loop is used to print the
 * name and number of each DirectoryEntry to the console.
 */
public void save() {
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("directory.txt", true)); 

        for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
            pw.write(x.getName());
            pw.write(x.getNumber());               
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        pw.close();    
    }
}




//Private helper methods

private void reallocate() {
    capacity = capacity * 2;
    DirectoryEntry[] newDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[capacity];
    System.arraycopy(theDirectory, 0, newDirectory,
            0, theDirectory.length);

    theDirectory = newDirectory;
}

private void add(String name, String telno) {
    if (size >= capacity) {
        reallocate();
    }
    theDirectory[size] = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);
    size = size + 1;
}

private int find(String name) {
    int i = 0;
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

@Override
public String format() {
    return null;
}
```

}

PhoneDirectory Code:

```
public interface PhoneDirectory {

/**
 * Load file containing directory entries
 *
 * @param sourceName is name of the file containing the directory entries
 */
void loadData(String sourceName);

/**
 * Look up an entry.
 *
 * @param name The name of person to look up
 * @return The telno or null if name is not in the directory
 */
String lookUpEntry(String name);

/**
 * Add new entry or change an existing entry.
 *
 * @param name The name of the person being added or whose telno is going to
 * change
 * @param telno The telno being changed or added
 * @return The old telno or if a new entry null
 */
String addChangeEntry(String name, String telno);

/**
 * Remove an entry from the directory.
 *
 * @param name The name of the person to be removed
 * @return The current telno. If not in the directory, null is returned.
 */
String removeEntry(String name);

/**
 * If the directory has been modified the contents of the directory are
 * written back to the file
 */
void save();

/**
 * Builds a single string representing directory contents Each entry is
 * terminated by a new line
 *
 * @return The formatted list of directory contents
 */
String format();
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the class PhoneDirectory and ArrayPhoneDirectory?

Comment: @L33D i have now added them to original post

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use JUnit tests for this and assertions to check the addiction, rather than printing into console. Anyway, the easiest way would probably be to implement the `toString` method of the `ArrayPhoneDirectory` and then call `System.out.println(newdir.toString())`. Inside the `toString`, you would just do `Arrays.toString(_theArray_)` or `Arrays.deepToString(_theArray)`.

**EDIT**: In the light of the code you've shown, it would be probably better to do the following:

```
Map<String, String> testValues = new HashMap<String, String();
testValues.put("Joe Perkins", "07762573872");
testValues.put("Annie Howell", "0876273862");
testValues.put("Buzz Killington", "99999999999");

for(String key : testValues.keySet()) {
    newdir.addChangeEntry(key, testValues.get(key));
}

for(String key : testValues.keySet()) {
    assert testValues.get(key).equals(newdir.lookUpEntry(key));
}
```

Of course you could just do `System.out.println` instead of the `assert` if you wish.

Comment: When I insert `System.out.println(newdir.toString());` into my tester class and run it, all that is printed is: ArrayPhoneDirectory@1fe5052b

Comment: That's because you didn't implement the `toString` method inside the `ArrayPhoneDirectory`. If you don't show the code or API of `ArrayPhoneDirectory` there is not much more I can help you with.

Comment: Sorry, please check the edit of the original post i have made which shows the ArrayPhoneDirectory code.